# Probability & darts(in Python)

Tags: probability, linear-programming

Suppose you toss a dart at a circular target of radius 10 inches. Given that the
dart lands in the upper half of the target, find the probability that

- its distance from the center is less than 5 inches.
- its distance from the center is greater than 5 inches.
- it lands within 5 inches of the point (0, 5).

Progress:(I made it in Python) for conditions less & greater I got $0.5$ each (not sure it's correct, I gave random for distance from the center) and I thought use function $X^2+Y^2 \le 25$, where $X$ is random $[-10,10]$ and $Y$ $[0,10]$;

for 3rd i thought to use equation $X^2+Y^2 \le 25$, where $X$ random $[-5,5]$ and Y $[0,10]$ and got about $0.4$ but i think it should be $0.5$, also. Help please!

Comment: It's just a relative area problem - with very simple shapes.  Why write a program? In fact, the mathematics of generating points randomly and uniformly is probably harder than answering the question directly.

Comment: I just should solve it using programming, it's one of the conditions)simulate this event

Answer (score 1):

As Mark McClure says, it is a simple areas problem.

You should at least sketch a picture to see why you first answer is wrong.

[image]

If you must program this then you can do as you suggest and take $X$ uniform on $[-10,10]$ and $Y$ uniform on $[0,10]$ using rejection sampling.  Then $(X,Y)$ is

- In the large semicircle if $X^2+Y^2 \le 10^2$
- Within $5$ of the centre if $X^2+Y^2 \le 5^2$
- Within $5$ of $(0,5)$ if $(X-0)^2+(Y-5)^2 \le 5^2$

You need to find what proportion of your random points which are in the larger semicircle also meet the other condition you are interested in.